# How to install vmware player tools for Ubuntu 14.4LTS?

Tags: unity

I want to know  steps to install vmware  player  tools  for  Ubuntu  14.4LTS  with command

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Insert the VMware Tools CD into Cd/DvR.

Mount the VMware Tools CD.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/cdrom
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom
```

Open the VMware Tools CD mounted on the Ubuntu desktop.

Right-click the file name that is similar to VMwareTools.x.x.x-xxxx.tar.gz.

Click Extract to, and select Ubuntu Desktop to save the extracted contents.

*The vmware-tools-distrib folder is extracted to the Ubuntu Desktop.*

Or open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

And run:

To find the exact name:

```
ls /mnt/cdrom
```

To extract the contents of the VMware Tools bundle:

```
tar xzvf /mnt/cdrom/VMwareTools-x.x.x-xxxx.tar.gz -C /home/{user}/Desktop/
```

To install VMware Tools

```
cd /home{user}/Desktop/vmware-tools-distrib
sudo ./vmware-install.pl -d
```

Restart the Ubuntu machine after the VMware Tools installation completes.

## [Source](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/login)